# Reading strings that contain whitespace into R from tab delimited .txt file

Tags: r, whitespace, read.table

I have a tab delimited text file which contains string names that include whitespace. It is the output of a python routine. The text file looks like this, with hidden '\t' characters.

```
Mother's Day    Breakfast in Bed    Breakfast in Bed    Arkadia Tea Chai Spice 240g 6.69    False
Mother's Day    Breakfast in Bed    Breakfast in Bed    Coles Crumpets 6 pack   2.29    False
Mother's Day    Entertainment   Entertainment   4 Ingredients Book 1 by Kim McCosker & Rachael Bermingham 1 each    14.00   False
Pantry  Baking  Cake Mix    White Wings Red Velvet Cake 425g    4.61    False
```

As the file is tab delimited, excel - for example - recognises that there are six columns - which is as i desire.

I wish for it to be in a table in R that has six columns, with the columns treated as factors.

I have read the docs, and it seems that specifying the delimiter ought to work -- however i cannot get this the following to work:

```
fullSurvey <- read.table(file="C:/1.txt", check.names=FALSE, header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

it returns:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 2 did not have 15 elements
```

Is this possible in R?

Comment: The data you have provided above has no tab characters in it. Also, the number of spaces between columns is variable. Assuming your text file is actually tab-delimited, try adding `quote=""` to your `read.table` call.

Comment: i have no idea what was going wrong - however the following worked: fullSurvey <- read.delim(file="C:/1.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=TRUE). @bdemarest -- i cut and paste it from vim, i am 100% confident it has tabs.

Comment: You data contains apostrophes (`'`) which are not quotation marks. `read.delim` uses `quote = "\""` whereas `read.table` uses `quote ="\"'"`. @bdemarest comment is the correct solution, but the default value of `read.delim` is double quotes only,  so it does work too.

Comment: thankyou both very much. While using delim seemed to solve the problem there were other random quote marks in the 25k rows, and it was your solution that crushed the bugs. i am most greatful.

Comment: Consolidated these comments into a community wiki answer. Feel free to add any details about what actually worked for you in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving comments to an answer to hopefully mark this as resolved).

Generally,  when your input is tab delimited,  you can try using `read.delim`, which,  like `read.csv` for csv files, would have generally sensible defaults for `read.table`.

When your data includes apostrophes,  single quotes, or double quotes,  you may need to specify the value to use for quoting characters, or specify `quote = ""` to preserve your embedded quotes.